# Migration to and from Azure Active directory

Tags: azure, migration, azure-active-directory

I have below scenario:

I have an Application XYZ, which allows user to create User ID and Password. These password are hashed with some salt and stored in a DB.

1. Now I want to migrate them to Azure AD B2C. Is it possible to migrate them with the Password Hash and salt in to Azure AD system and it working seamlessly.
2. In the above scenario, if we have the Password in AD, is it possible to extract them, so that if we plan to start using our own DB schema it can work?

Comment: Can you decrypt the passwords stored in your DB?

Comment: Did you refer to this [Migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to migrate them with the Password Hash and salt in to
>   Azure AD system and it working seamlessly.

No, we cannot migrate them with hashed passwords. But we can migrate those users to Azure and reset their passwords for them. For more details about Azure AD B2C User migration, please refer to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration).

> In the above scenario, if we have the Password in AD, is it possible
>   to extract them, so that if we plan to start using our own DB schema
>   it can work?

Unfortunately, you cannot get users' passwords from Azure. This is because Azure AD password protections.

Hope this helps!